# jquery array return in function

Tags: arrays, return

I have a Jquery for Password-correction and it works fine, if I use the 2 Lines
        //      $('#minimum span').show();
        //      $('#minimum').addClass('boldgreen');
But I´ve tryed to put that out in a seperat function, and the return is what I want, if I alert(ret[0]);
But it doesn´t change the css in the html code.
I´ve tryed many ways, but without any result.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

```
var cssPassword = function(cssId, cssClass, hideShow, removeAddClass)
  {
    var IDKlasse = "$('" + cssId + " span')." + hideShow +"();";
    var cssKlasse = "$('" + cssId + "')." + removeAddClass + "('" + cssClass + "');";
    var cssArray = new Array();

    cssArray[0] = IDKlasse;
    cssArray[1] = cssKlasse;

    return cssArray;
  }

function()
...
        if(passwordNew.length > 7) {
          var ret =  cssPassword('#minimum', 'green', 'show', 'addClass');
          //eval(ret[0]);
          //eval(ret[1]);
          strength += 1;
          alert(ret[1]);
    //      $('#minimum span').show();
    //      $('#minimum').addClass('boldgreen');
        }else{
...
```